# PowerShell - Get-MessageTrackingReport how to specify start and end time of current process

Tags: powershell

could you please help me? I need to specify start and end time of current process with **Get-MessageTrackingReport** command. I know you can do it with **Get-MessageTrackingLog**:

```
$start = (Get-Date).Addhours(-1)
$end = (Get-Date)
Get-MessageTrackingLog -EvenId Receive -Start $start -End $end
```

But for my purposes I really need to do it with **Get-MessageTrackingReport** command, so how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm using Get-MessageTrackingReport anyaway but what criteria do I need?

Comment: Earlier comment wasnt well enough researched. Why is `Get-MessageTrackingLog` not good enough in this case. `Get-MessageTrackingReport`'s documented use is to see an email report between one and many parties. You would look at the documentation and see that it obviously does not support dates.

Comment: @Matt I'm not using `Get-MessageTrackingLog` cause I can't get Sender's Name with that which is I really need! So I'm using `Get-MessageTrackingReport` instead but facing this problem above and don't know how to solve it! Could anyone help me please I'm really straggling right now!